# PHP arrays: extract one dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like:

```
$fields = array(
  "f1" => array("test"),
  "f2" => array("other" => "values")
);
```

I'd like to retrive this information in one array:

```
$first_dimension = array("f1","f2");
```

Is there a function in PHP that can extract a particular dimension of an array directly? Is there a syntax shortcut for this?

Comment: missing `array` in line 1 and `;` in line 4

Comment: I've updated the syntax Imran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/array_keys).

```
$fields = array(
  'f1' => array('test'),
  'f2' => array('other' => 'values'),
);
$keys = array_keys($fields);
```

Comment: missing `array` in line 1 and `;` on line 4

Comment: Look through all other array_ functions - there are a lot of them and they do lots and lots of different things [and generally make your life a lot easier].

Answer (score 0):

$fields['f2'][other']

To access it directly